# What does $scope:scope mean in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following official tutorial of Angularjs and I'm stuck at the step 2.

Here is a snippet where I don't understand the meaning of `$scope:scope`,

```
describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

  it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});

    expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
  }));

});
```

I guess it's a key value pair but scope is initialized to `{}`, how come it has a `phones` as its member element? Can anyone explain it what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a test. This line:

```
ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});
```

injects scope as an empty object into your actual controller. Your test ensures that the controller sets a `phones` property on the scope, with a length of 3.